# grep for pattern with special character and output only matched string

Tags: grep

Team,

I want to grep for a substring container - and then only output that string and not whole line. how can i? I know i can awk on space and pull using $ but want to know how to do in grep?

```
echo $test_pods_info | grep -F 'test-'
```

output

```
test-78ac951e-89a6-4199-87a4-db8a1b8b054f export-9b55f0d5-071d-431-1d2ux0-avexport-xavierisp-sjc4--a4dd85-102 1/1 Running 0 19h
```

expected output

```
test-78ac951e-89a6-4199-87a4-db8a1b8b054f
```

Answer (score 2):

`awk` is more suitable for this as you want to get first field in a matching line:

```
awk '/test-/{print $1}' <<< "$taxIncluded"
```

```
test-78ac951e-89a6-4199-87a4-db8a1b8b054f
```

If you really want to use `grep` then this might be what you're looking for:

```
grep -o 'test-\S*' <<< "$taxIncluded"
```

or:

```
grep -o 'test-[^[:space:]]*' <<< "$taxIncluded"
```

Comment: I've tested your second grep statement and it doesn't work on my machine without -E (gnu grep 3.1)

Comment: I have tested thode `grep` commands on BSD and gnu versions and `-E` wasn't required anywhere. See this demo: https://ideone.com/8msLEK

Comment: I was on Windows 10 Linux Subsystem - Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo $test_pods_info | grep -o 'test-'
```

the `-o` option is:

> show[ing] only the part of a line matching PATTERN

according to `grep --help`. Of course, this will only print `test-`, so you'll need to rework your regex:

```
grep -oE '(test).*[[:space:]]\b'
```

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out..

```
echo $test_pods_info | grep -o "\test-\w*-\w*\-\w*\-\w*\-\w*"
```

outoput

```
test-78ac951e-89a6-4199-87a4-db8a1b8b054f
```

but i wish there is simple way. like \test-*\